# Hint with floors and ceiling proof

Tags: ceiling-and-floor-functions

Prove that $$\forall n \in \mathbb{Z},\left \lceil \frac{n-1}{2} \right\rceil = \left\lfloor \frac{n}{2} \right\rfloor$$

I decided to approach it by extending floor and ceiling definition and got
$$ \frac{n-1}{2} \leq \left\lceil \frac{n-1}{2} \right\rceil = \left\lfloor \frac{n}{2} \right\rfloor \leq \frac{n}{2} $$
And now I am stuck with $$\frac{n}{2} = \frac{n-1}{2} $$
which only made it worse.
Any advice or hint on how I can approach this proof differently?

Comment: Why $\frac{n-1}{2} \geq \lceil \frac{n-1}{2} \rceil$, when it should be $\frac{n-1}{2} \le \lceil \frac{n-1}{2} \rceil$?

Comment: Maybe by induction, prove two base cases, then assume the $n=k$ case and prove both the $n=k+2$ and $n=k-2$ cases?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to prove that $\lfloor \frac{n}{2}\rfloor$ = $\lceil \frac{n-1}{2}\rceil$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1862671/how-to-prove-that-lfloor-fracn2-rfloor-lceil-fracn-12-rceil) - found using an [Approach0 search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Cleft%5Clceil%5Cfrac%7Bn-1%7D%7B2%7D%5Cright%5Crceil%3D%5Cleft%5Clfloor%5Cfrac%7Bn%7D%7B2%7D%5Cright%5Crfloor%24%2C%20OR%20content%3Aintegers&p=1). FYI, another post's [answer](/a/1832631) mentions doing the same thing, i.e., check the even & odd integers separately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $n = 2m + 1$ for some $m \in \mathbb{Z}$. In this case, $\displaystyle \left\lceil \frac{n-1}{2} \right\rceil = m$. Similarly, $\displaystyle \left\lfloor \frac{n}{2} \right\rfloor = \left\lfloor m + \frac{1}{2} \right\rfloor = m$. Consequently, $\displaystyle \left\lceil \frac{n-1}{2} \right\rceil = \left\lfloor \frac{n}{2} \right\rfloor$.

We can similarly consider the case $n = 2m$. For this case, $\displaystyle \left\lfloor \frac{n}{2} \right\rfloor = m$ and $\displaystyle \left\lceil \frac{n-1}{2} \right\rceil = \left\lceil m - \frac{1}{2} \right\rceil = m$. Once again, we can conclude $\displaystyle \left\lceil \frac{n-1}{2} \right\rceil = \left\lfloor \frac{n}{2} \right\rfloor$, giving us the required result.

Answer (score 4):

I'd try splitting it into $n$ even and $n$ odd.

If $n$ is even then $n = 2k$ with $k$ an integer, and

$$\lceil\frac{n-1}{2}\rceil = \lceil\frac{2k-1}{2}\rceil = \lceil k - (1/2)\rceil = k.$$

You asked for just a hint so does this help?